# How to update arraylist if a programatically made editext is removed?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hi i have been working on a project where i have to make a plus button and onclick of that plus button a i'm inflating a new layout which consits of two editext and one remove image.
So  far it is working as expected but the problem is that when i click on remove image editext of that particular row is removed however the data is still being sent to database.
I tried using remove method of arraylist but still it is not working.
So please could someone help me out here.

Here is my code for layout inflation

```
public void makedifferentEditText() {
        try {

            View secondchild = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.update_extra_links_layout, null);
            final LinearLayout update_extra_links_layout = (LinearLayout) secondchild.findViewById(R.id.update_extra_links_layout);
            customtextTitle = (CustomEditTextThin) secondchild.findViewById(R.id.google_edit_link);
            customeditTextLink = (CustomEditTextThin) secondchild.findViewById(R.id.facebook_edit_link);
            eexId = (TextView) secondchild.findViewById(R.id.eeid);
            google_tilte.add(customtextTitle);
            google_link.add(customeditTextLink);
            extId.add(eexId);
            Log.e("title", google_tilte.toString());
            Log.e("link", google_link.toString());

            AppCompatImageView removeimage = (AppCompatImageView) secondchild.findViewById(R.id.icon_remove_link);
            rAlign.addView(update_extra_links_layout);
            int indexValue = rAlign.indexOfChild(update_extra_links_layout);
            update_extra_links_layout.setTag(indexValue);

            int ImagePosition = rAlign.indexOfChild(update_extra_links_layout);// update_extra_links_layout.indexOfChild(removeimage);
            removeimage.setTag(ImagePosition);
            removeimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        int index = (int) view.getTag();
                        // if (index != -1) {
                        if (rAlign.getChildCount()>1) {

                            // int index = rAlign.indexOfChild(update_extra_links_layout);
                            rAlign.removeViewAt(index);
                            google_tilte.remove(index);
                            google_link.remove(index);
                            extId.remove(index);
                            //customtextTitle.setText("");
                            //customeditTextLink.setText("");
                        }
                        //}
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and Here is the code for adding data to database

```
if (google_link != null && google_link.size() > 0) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < google_link.size(); j++) {
                            /*arrayTitle.add(google_link.get(j).getText().toString());
                            Log.e("array", arrayTitle.toString());*/

                            ExtraLinksObject links4 = new ExtraLinksObject();

                            String othergoogleTitle = google_tilte.get(j).getText().toString();//customtextTitle.getText().toString();
                            String othergooglelink = google_link.get(j).getText().toString();//customeditTextLink.getText().toString()
                            String googleId = extId.get(j).getText().toString();//eexId.getText().toString();
                            links4.setLink(othergooglelink);
                            links4.setTitle(othergoogleTitle);
                            links4.setExID(googleId);

                            extraLinks.add(links4);

                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `RecyclerView` with adapter?

Comment: @Mosius i dont how i can get the editext values from adapter.so if you like to put some more light on it.

Comment: You are adding Linearlayout to parent layout. Try to replace `rAlign.addView(update_extra_links_layout);`  with  `rAlign.addView(secondchild);` It may work

Comment: @cooldev you can set textChangeListener for editText to update your data in the list

Comment: @Suraj i tried but still the same

Comment: @Mosius what are you talking about..